# Is the log of epsilon a negative number?

Tags: limits

I'm unsure about the prospect of this. It would be great if someone could help.

Comment: what is epsilon? Try adding some more details to your question

Answer (score 3):

That depends: Assuming $\epsilon \in \mathbb R^+$:

- If $\epsilon > 1$ then $\log(\epsilon) > 0$;
- if $\epsilon = 1$ then $\log(\epsilon) = 0$;
- if $0 < \epsilon < 1$ then $\log(\epsilon) < 0$.